# What is wrong with this scope?

Tags: javascript

When an HTML form submits, it should run the code inside the IF statement and then console log it. But all I get logged into the console is `undefined`. What's wrong with this code?

```js
let inputValue = document.getElementById('nicInput').value;
let invChars;
if(/[^A-Za-z0-9]/.test(inputValue)) {
    let invChars = true;
 } else {
    let invChart = false;
 }
 console.log(invChars);
```

Comment: You declared three different `let invChart` variables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`let` creates a new variable in the scope of the block it appears in.

So `let invChars;` is a different variable to `let invChars = true;`.

It is the former that `console.log(invChars);` refers to, and you never assign it a value.

---

To take your approach, you should simple not redeclare the variable inside the blocks of `if` and `else`:

```
let inputValue = document.getElementById('nicInput').value;
let invChars;
if(/[^A-Za-z0-9]/.test(inputValue)) {
    invChars = true;
 } else {
    invChart = false;
 }
 console.log(invChars);
```

---

That said, that is an exceptionally inefficient way to assign `true` or `false` based on the return value of `test()` … which itself returns `true` or `false`.

It would be easier, faster, and clearer to simply:

```
let inputValue = document.getElementById('nicInput').value;
let invChars = /[^A-Za-z0-9]/.test(inputValue);
console.log(invChars);
```

Answer (score 0):

> "[let](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let)" defines a new block level variable.

You wish to conditionally assign value to the same variable invChars and so, your code should be like this:

```
let inputValue = document.getElementById('nicInput').value;
let invChars;
if(/[^A-Za-z0-9]/.test(inputValue)) {
    invChars = true;
 } else {
    invChart = false;
 }
 console.log(invChars);
```

or since the test() returns a boolean, you could just assign it directly to the variable:

```
let invChars = /[^A-Za-z0-9]/.test(inputValue);
console.log(invChars);
```